# What improvements does SpaceX Falcon 9 Block 5 have over prior version?

Tags: spacex, falcon-9, engineering

Does SpaceX disclose what improvements their Falcon 9 Block 5 will have over the Block 4 model? If so, what improved features will it have?

I have heard general comments about it in the news, but I am unaware if they provide any technical details.

Comment: The general comments in the news are the only details SpaceX have published.

Comment: Great post, isn't there a specially designed heat shield as well protecting the Dragon capsule from the lower fuel tanks?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[This article](http://theclimategap.com/falcon9-evolution/) provides great summary of Falcon 9 evolution, including changes in the Block 5 version.

In short (from this article):

- Black interstage, landing legs, and raceway
- Retractable landing legs
- Redesigned composite overwrapped pressure vessel (COPV) which hold helium – Both to account for Amos-6 disaster and to handle many reuses
- Redesigned turbopumps. – NASA required SpaceX to redesign its Merlin turbopumps for  crew rating after recaptured units showed
  stress cracks in the turbopump blades
- Other general Merlin engine improvements – Thrust increased to 190,000lbf
- Redesign and requalification of active components – Valves for “longer duration and higher levels”
- Redesign of octaweb thrust structure – Bolted rather than welded
- Optimized for reusability – Can refly a dozen or so times with inspections and up to 100 flights with refurbishments.
- “Aiming for two flights within 24 hours”

Comment: Clarified COPV acronym